# add custom class dynamically to dc.selectMenu; IE11 removes it

Tags: css, d3.js, internet-explorer-11, dc.js

When dynamically adding custom css classes to a dc.selectMenu IE11 kicks them out when filters are applied. For now I push them in again using a renderlet. This causes "glitches"/moves content around due to added padding or widths/heights.

You can reproduce the issue by selecting an option from the select box in my [block](https://bl.ocks.org/tomschulze/1d8ca1a7420b78baaac513d7d98de8e4).

Is this a bug? Does anyone know a cleaner workaround not causing these glitches to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that IE11 actually [crashes on Win8 if you try to update a selectMenu](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1334)! So [we only render, don't attempt to redraw](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1338) selectMenu on that browser.

So that's why you need to re-apply it.

In experimenting with this, I found that it was enough simply to move

```
.on('renderlet', ...
```

to the `selectMenu`, where it arguably belongs (because it's modifying that widget). I think this works because the select menu doesn't use any transitions, and there is no delay.

More generally, though, in any modern version of dc.js, you should really use the `pretransition` event, which fires before any transitions. In sum:

```
selectMenu.on('pretransition', function(chart){
    selectMenu.select('select').classed('uk-select', true);
});
```

Although it's a really cool word, `renderlet` is rarely the right event to listen to. You'll see it in a lot of examples because it goes way back to early releases of dc.js, but it occurs after all transitions have finished.

If you use `pretransition` you'll have a chance to change things before the browser even refreshes at all.

Comment: thanks, that was really helpful! thank you also for explaining why this issue occurs at all.